# Backup a Windows with an equivalent of rsync on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, ntfs, synchronization

I have a computer with a dual boot, a Linux and a Windows.

My Linux is backuped with RSYNC on a NAS and it works fine.

And from my linux I want to do the same thing with my Windows partition. So i mount my partition and do a RSYNC betwen my partition and my NAS (which has a NTFS partition).

But when I restore my save on a other computer, I have some issues. I tried with different arguments but in the most efficient case Windows boot but the start menu is broken. I think it comes from rights (ACLS) issues.

The only solution i have found it's to use NTSFCLONE, but it's take to much time to re-write each time i want to restore my clean config.

Is there an other way to do it with a linux ? I want to sync two NTFS partitions. Or should I ignore some directory to reduce the chances of having a problem ?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to what it's asking. Are you trying to mount your Windows partition, in which case it's most likely a duplicate that should be closed? Are you trying to rsync with a remote filesystem that happens to be on NTFS?

Comment: I edited my post to be more specific

Comment: "_when I restore my save on a other computer, I have some issues_" what issues?